# How to fix "TypeError: this.getElement(...) is null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating an array which will include the heights of some components in my app.


for doing that I had to get the elements and their heights.
I did it by this function:

```
getElement(method, elem){
    switch (method){
      case 'id':
        return document.getElementById(elem);
      case 'class':
        return document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
      case 'name':
        return document.getElementsByName(elem);
      case 'tagName':
        return document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
      default:
        console.error('Incorrect use of getElement method')
    }
  }
```

and then I was inserting the heights of the elements by this function to my array:

```
  heightsArr = [
    this.getElement('id', 'home').clientHeight,
    this.getElement('id', 'services').clientHeight
  ]
```

but then I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: this.getElement(...) is null
```

I was trying to move the array to `componentDidMount()` function, and then the error disappeared.
but then when I called the array, it returned me `undefined`

When it was in the `componentDidMount()` I was trying to do `console.log()` to the array, and it returns the array as expected with all of the heights

I'm trying to set set this array as `NavBar` component by this code:

```
<NavBar heights={this.heightsArr}></NavBar>
```

but when I was inspecting the component by react addon for firefox, I saw that the props of the component are

```
{
   heights: undefined
}
```

how can I fix it?

## EDIT:

Now it's working and with the react inpector on the browser, I see that the heights are finnaly props of `NavBar`.

I'm setting the `props` as property of an object in an array, but when I'm logging to the console the value of that property I'm getting undefined.

My code that assigning the `props` to the object is:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.sections.map(section => {
      section.height = this.props.heights
    })
}
```

Should I move this `map` function to `componentDidUpdate()` instead of `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: Not sure why you need that custom function for. In any case, are you sure the component you want to get from the DOM is actually mounted? If not, your function will return `null` thus you cannot get `clientHeight` from that.

Comment: That's not how ReactJS is designed to get elements, normally you'd use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but even that is discouraged in most cases. What exactly are you trying to achieve? It seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: When you are working within react you almost never use dom queries.

Comment: @Chris When it was in the componentDidMount() I was trying to do console.log() to the array, and it returns the array as expected with all of the heights so the getElement function is working

Comment: Yes, but you are trying to use the height as a prop... which is before the component mounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React has access to the virtual DOM rather than the one you typically interact with using traditional dom selectors. To coordinate with React's lifecycle events, you should use React `refs` instead.

Consider this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wood-bp95g

Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      totalHeight: 0
    };

    this.home = React.createRef();
    this.services = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let allHeights = 0;
    const refs = [this.home, this.services];

    refs.forEach(ref => {
      allHeights += ref.current.clientHeight;
    });

    this.setState({
      totalHeight: allHeights
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Height: {this.state.totalHeight}</h4>
        <div ref={this.home} style={{ height: "500px", background: "blue" }}>
          Home Section
        </div>
        <div
          ref={this.services}
          style={{ height: "300px", background: "green" }}
        >
          Services
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Refs give you access to the same element properties and methods you would with traditional selectors. In this case, we give each `<div>` tag a `ref`. Inside componentDidMount(), which is triggered right after the first render, we can tap into the height of these mounted elements using their `.clientHeight` as expected.

We iterate over the `refs` to get the total height and update our `totalHeight` state-value. Similarly you can pass in that state to your Navbar component like:

`<Navbar height={this.state.heights}/>`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting now this error:
`TypeError: ref.current is null`

Comment: @HillelTech components cannot accept a ref property. What you can do is wrap the component in a div, and give that div the ref. So for the Home component do: `<div  ref={this.home}><Home/></div>` and repeat for the Services component.

Comment: Now it's working and with the react inpector on the browser, I see that the heights are finnaly props of `NavBar`
I'm setting the props as property of an object in an array, but when I'm logging to the console the value of that property I'm getting undefined

Comment: Hmm might just be a timing issue, The Navbar component renders before the componentDidMount() logic in the Parent component executes. So if you run a console.log(this.props.heights) in Navbar it will be undefined until you get updated props. Try using componentDidUpdate() to get the updated props data :)

Comment: Exactly what I thought ;)

Comment: @HillelTech sweet! You're welcome. Please consider upvoting :)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can control element for not null or undefined on insert to array:

```
heightsArr = [
    this.getElement('id', 'home') && this.getElement('id', 'home').clientHeight,
    this.getElement('id', 'services') && this.getElement('id', 'services').clientHeight
  ]
```